# How to clip/symmetrical difference a shapefile and ArcGIS Mapserver layer?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server, qgis-plugins, qgis-2, map-service

I have 2 layers. A portion of a shapefile and an ArcGIS Mapserver layer. I would like to subtract the satellite image area outside the shapefile (the rectangle) from the view. IOW, leave only the area inside the shapefile with the satellite view. screenshot is attached. My problem is when I try Vector --> Geoprocessing Tools --> the satellite layer is not seen. I have tried exporting the sat layer to a tiff. No luck.
I have tried everything I can think of and Googled this to death. Can anyone offer suggestions?

[image: sat + shapefile]

Answer (score 1):

This might be a round about way to do it, but you could take a screenshot of the satellite image, upload it as a separate layer, georeference it, then clip it.

Comment: A roundabout way is fine with me. I'm very new to this and have already tried saving the layer as a GeoTIFF and added it. It still doesn't show up in those tools.  But I didn't georeference it. I didn't know I had to. I'm too green, I guess. I'll try this procedure and let you know.

Comment: All clip features must be polygons. This is probably your issue. I would try editing it in another program. There are good free knockoffs to adobe illustrator that will allow you to clip images. You won't be able to clip an image in arcmap or QGIS. You can also import vector layers (roads, polygons) to illustrator-like programs to use as an overlay on your map.

Comment: Do you have access to ArcMap at all?